# How do I save the values from every iteration of a for-loop?

Tags: matlab

I have a for-loop, but every iteration overwrites the variable and I have only the final data left.

How can I save the other values from every iteration of the for-loop?

---

*Here is the code I tried:*

```
p = [1:1:20]';
for x = 0.1:0.1:1
   q = x.*p
end
```

*Here is the result I got:*

```
q =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `q` a two-dimensional matrix or a cell.

Two-dimensional matrix:

```
q=zeros(numel(p),10); %better to pre-allocate if you know the dimensions beforehand.
count=0;

for x=.1:.1:1
   count=count+1;
   q(:,count)=x.*p;
end
```

Cell:

```
q=cell(10); %better to pre-allocate if you know the dimensions beforehand.
count=0;

for x=.1:.1:1
   count=count+1;
   q{count}=x.*p;
end
```

Comment: @AbdulAsad Please accept the answer by clicking checking it on the left, so that it gets off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution use `bsxfun()` It multiplies each `x` index with `p'` in just one line

```
p = [1:1:20]';
x = 0.1:0.1:1;
q = bsxfun(@times,x,p)
```